# Magento1.9 : An error occurred while processing this directive

Tags: magento-1.9

I Configure Sub domain Unfortunetley I got this error

> [an error occurred while processing this directive]

I don't Know What is the problem on it. Front end it's opening but it show's this error Backend it redirect to Live Backend.

I don't know it's related to server error or Magento Error can any one please guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1: Enable Error Printing in PHP OR Enable DEVELOPER_MODE**

In order to find out the bug, enable errors for your PHP.

From http://www.phpfunctionalism.com/config/error-reporting/:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
```

If that doesn't work, edit php.ini (see http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) and set:

```
display_errors=1
```

If you don't know where your php.ini is located use:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

And locate *"configuration file (php.ini) path"*.

**Step 2: Debug your Apache / Web Server Log**

If you still don't get any errors in PHP, the problem has to be with web server:

If you are using Apache, locate `access.log` and `error.log` and see if they contain messages related to this issue.

Hint: `tail -f xxx.log` allows you to track changes in a log in real-time (very useful for debugging).

**Step 3: Check directory and file permission**

Directory permission must be 755 other permissions like (752, 753, 756, and 777) cause limitation and will not work..

File permission must be 644 other permissions like (642, 643, 646 and 647) cause limitation and will not work..

Comment: I tried all no solution

Comment: Checked apache log?

Comment: It's server error or Magento error

Comment: Where to check in var folder i didn't find

Comment: It's web server error. Do you have access to server error log? Check my second step

Comment: How to check this

Comment: You can find error log in your server's `/var/log/apache2` directory. as `error.log`. Refer this : http://askubuntu.com/questions/14763/where-are-the-apache-and-php-log-files

Comment: I can't find this files in my server

Comment: Which server are you using? Is it linux?.  if it is linux check here http://askubuntu.com/questions/14763/where-are-the-apache-and-php-log-files

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the

```
magentosourcedirectory/var/tmp
```

folder exists in the Magento root directory and that the web user has permissions to write in it.

hope this will work for you.

Comment: No temp folder on that Location

Comment: Please create one and then assign appropriate permissions so web server user can write

Answer (score -1):

You can solve this error by just one PHP script.
Download it by this site:- https://wpbloggerbasic.com/special-guide/an-error-occurred-while-processing-this-directive/